# css wave animation bug

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this css animation, which should represent waves. But somehow they keep disappearing and appearing somewhere else....

This is my HTML:

```css
.waves-section {
  background-color: #0033C7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
}

section .wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('./../../../assets/wave.png');
  background-size: 100% 20vh;
}

section .wave.wave1 {
  animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  bottom: 0;
}

section .wave.wave2 {
  animation: animate2 17s linear infinite;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation-delay: -5s;
  bottom: 0;
}

section .wave.wave3 {
  animation: animate2 17s linear infinite;
  z-index: 998;
  opacity: 0.7;
  animation-delay: -2s;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 100vh;
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="waves-section">
  <div class="wave wave1"></div>
  <div class="wave wave2"></div>
  <div class="wave wave3"></div>
</section>
```

Detail error: the waves keep lagging around in the div. I am using also a picture for the waves:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z33M.png)

Comment: you probably want 100vw and not 100vh in the background position

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes animate{
   from{
        background-position-x: 0;
    }
    to{
        background-position-x: 100vh;
    }
}

@keyframes animate2{
    from{
        background-position-x: 100vh;
    }
    to{
        background-position-x: 0;
    }
}
```

for animation continuity the second animation should start form 100vh to 0vh